Время выполнения блоков кода
Обнаружил некоторую странность связанную с производительностью кода.
Ниже приведён код небольшой учебной программы. Он выполняет вывод текста в консоль, а так же фиксирует и выводит время выполнения вывода.
Если запустить его, то будет видно, что на первый вывод в консоль, тратится очень много времени, относительно всех остальных выводов. Примерно 80000 тиков, хотя в остальных случаях вывод займёт около 200. И это вполне объяснимо, т.к. в этот момент видимо происходит инициализация класса Console.
Но дальше я обнаружил некоторые странности.

Console.WriteLine(i) выводится дольше чем Console.WriteLine("a" + i), и это выглядит крайне нелогичным и не очевидным. Ведь во втором случае добавляется же ещё и конкатенация строк. Почему же вывести int в консоль оказывается дороже, чем вывести строку в которую сконкатенирован int?

Понятно, что время выполнения может сильно гулять, но я заметил странную закономерность. Первый вывод во втором цикле всегда занимает в 2-3 раза больше тиков, чем последующие. Сперва я предположил, что возможно в этот момент происходит инициализация конструкции for, но тогда бы наверное тот же эффект наблюдался бы и в третьем цикле? А его нет. Почему так?


  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new();
            stopwatch.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);

            //Первый цикл
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
            }
                
            //Второй цикл
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                Console.WriteLine("Hello, World! " + $"{i}");
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
            }

            //Третий цикл
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                Console.WriteLine("Hello, People! " + $"{i}");
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
            }

        }


Это очень сильно зависит от среды выполнения. И в целом имеет смыл мерить не отдельные итерации циклов, а делать к примеру 100 итераций и смотреть, за какое время они выполнятся в целом. И вот тогда выяснится, что числа выводятся быстрее всего, статический текст выводится медленнее, а текст с интерполяцией данных - ещё медленнее. Как и должно быть. Отдельные измерения очень сильно будут зависеть от того, в каком порядке они сделаны друг за другом. Там очень много всяких "ленивых" инициализаций, поэтому в первый раз действительно многие штуки будут выполняться медленнее, чем в последующие.

Попробуйте перенести первый цикл в конец.

Не меряйте вывод в консоль. Всё остальное - да, в т. ч. подготовку строки к выводу.

Ну и, кроме всего прочего, вывод в консоль - это заведомо самое медленное, что бывает в коде. Поэтому если вы это всё делаете с целью дальнейшего ускорения работы кода, то самое оптимальное - просто максимально выкинуть вывод в консоль из программы. А ещё лучше - сделать вывод в файл вместо консоли (тоже сократив его по максимуму). Поэтому мерить скорость вывода в консоль - занятие на практике бесполезное. Ну, если вы не пишете какую-то утилиту, которая обязательно должна интенсивно выводить что-то в консоль.

"Hello, World! " + $"{i}" - откуда такая конструкция? Вот $"Hello, World! {i}".

В общем, вывод на консоль в Windows - это крайне недерминированный процесс по критерию времени выполнения.

Вы никогда не сможете замерить корректно время в отладке для одного вызова, точность таймера не позволит это сделать адекватно. 1) нужно запускать релизную сборку а не отладочную, 2) мерять сразу 1000 или на порядки больше итераций. А если вообще по-честному реализовать измерения, то никаких Stopwatch, а только Benchmark.NET. А пока у вас погрешность примерно 100-200%. То есть причина задания вопроса не доказана ничем.

Сперва происходит JIT-компиляция кода. Поэтому первый запуск любого метода всегда медленнее, чем последующие. (Оставим в стороне ngen, tiered compilation, ready to run и AOT).

Если беспокоит именно скорость вывода в консоль, то есть способы многократно повысить её, работая напрямую с потоком.

скорость вывода в консоль двух типов: когда юзер пишет что-то к консоль, тут задержек быть не должно, а есть другой тип: когда куча строк валится в консоль откуда то, например из внешнего буфера - нет смысла рендерить всё, есть смысл рендерить последние 25 строк, но тогда такая консоль способна рендерить да хоть миллиард строк за 1 фрейм, потому что возьмёт из буфера последние 25 строк - их и выведет, а остальные сроки - скипнет; это графоний и это сложно, потому что это графический движок, который не завезли в консоли, впрочем, в мою консоль - завезли, я сам взял да и завёз себе всё что нужно

проблема майкрософтовской консоли [впрочем, это не проблема, она писана в 1993-ем, и скорее всего написана в айбиэме], и любой другой консоли в том, что консоли пытаются отрендерить каждую влетающую в них строку - это и есть критическая ошибка; рендер ограничен в возможностях, и насколько я помню что-то типа больше чем 40к строк/сек не выводится [причём ядро долбится в сотку], но зачем выводить все 40к строк в эту секунду - это и есть главный вопрос

Вот тут будет понятный результат:
// Framework 4.8
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        long et; string s; int i, j, loops = 1000, sops = 1000;
        Action<long> cwl = (eltcks) => Console.WriteLine("Average time {0}", eltcks / loops);
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        for (et = 0, i = 0; i < loops; i++) { //Первый цикл
            stopwatch.Restart();
            for (j = 0; j < sops; j++) s = i.ToString();
            et += stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
        }
        cwl(et);
        for (et = 0, i = 0; i < loops; i++) { //Второй цикл
            stopwatch.Restart();
            for (j = 0; j < sops; j++) s = String.Format("Hello, World! {0}", i);
            et += stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
        }
        cwl(et);
        for (et = 0, i = 0; i < loops; i++) { //Третий цикл
            stopwatch.Restart();
            for (j = 0; j < sops; j++) s = String.Format("Hello, People! {0}", i);
            et += stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
        }
        cwl(et);
        for (et = 0, i = 0; i < loops; i++) { //Первый цикл
            stopwatch.Restart();
            for (j = 0; j < sops; j++) s = i.ToString();
            et += stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
        }
        cwl(et);
    }
}

-->

Average time 315
Average time 997
Average time 1050
Average time 301


Может человека именно вывод в консоль интересует ))  А не форматирование.

Не используйте String.Format, вместо этого, если возможно, следует использовать интерполяцию строк, она лучше оптимизирована в последних версиях .NET.

@aepot это код для Framework 4.8, там нет интерполяции строк.

А зачем вам Framework 4.8? У автора, очевидно, интерполяция есть.

@aepot потому что он стоит на корпоративном устройстве, и ничего другого я поставить не могу. Если у автора есть интерполяция - пусть использует. На обсуждаемый вопрос это не влияет.

Плохие у вас админы, сочувствую.

@aepot админы хорошие, это я плохой - занимаюсь всякой фигнёй в рабочее время. С утра вместо зарядки для поднятия тонуса.

Так договоритесь, чтобы .NET 8 SDK накатили. Это вопрос трёх минут, и времени будете меньше тратить, потому что он быстрее работает.

Эта проблема давно замечена, решается выводом в консоль строк, равных количеству буфера строк консоли.
Таким образом буфер консоли инициализируется полностью, и консоль становится стабильной.
Узнать количество строк буфера текущей консоли можно через класс System.Console.
Можете написать собственный класс консоли, от него наследоваться. Этот класс при инициализации будет сам чекать настройки консоли, и выводить нужное количество строк для первой полной инициализации буфера.
ПС: Заметьте - когда буфер полностью инициализирован, и вы шлёте в консоль что-то совсем простое для вывода - память консоли стоит колом, вообще не меняется.
Какой то код писать - бессмысленно, он слишком прост.
for (i=0; i<System.Console.ВзятьПолнуюВысотуБуфера; i++)
    System.Console.WriteLine(ВывестиСтрокуДлинойВБуфер);

